# Why does !!! on a list of strings does not work as intended in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to use !!! operator of `tidyr`.

The following code does not work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a = data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,3),y=c(11,11,22,33),z=c(111,111,111,222))

cols = c('x','z')
a %>% group_by(!!!cols) %>% summarize(count=n())
```

I wanted the output to be same as the following:

```
a %>% group_by(x,z) %>% summarize(count=n())
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   x [3]
#       x     z count
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1   111     2
# 2     2   111     1
# 3     3   222     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `syms` to convert the string to symbol, then do the evaluation (`!!!`) and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(!!! rlang::syms(cols)) %>%
  summarize(count=n())
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
#      x     z count
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1   111     2
#2     2   111     1
#3     3   222     1
```

Instead of doing this with `group_by/summarise`, can also do `count`

```
a %>%
   count(!!! rlang::syms(cols))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     z     n
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1   111     2
#2     2   111     1
#3     3   222     1
```

Or use `group_by_at`

```
a %>%
  group_by_at(cols) %>%
  summarize(count=n())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer :-)